# Cannot see backup files in localhost

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, database-backups

I'm writing a php script to get a backup of a database in MySql and following is my script.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$d= date('d.m.y_H.i');
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$table_name = "redcap_data";
$backup_file  = "backups/$d.sql";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name INTO OUTFILE '$backup_file'";

mysql_select_db('test2');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not take data backup: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Backedup  data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Script runs very well. But when I go to localhost/backups (where I want to save my backups) I cannot see any backups made by the script. Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Enable error reporting using error_reporting(E_ALL); http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you are trying will provide you backup of data but not logical backup like .sql.

If you want just data backup then @Drew has provided you solution but if you want to take backup in .sql format then use dump method which will also be fast and you can also avoid locking.

command is here-

```
mysqldump -u<user> -p<pass> mydb mytable > /path/mybackup.sql
```

To avoid locking, use --single-transaction option-

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u<user> -p<pass> mydb mytable > /path/mybackup.sql
```